# Azure Pull Request | Azure Devops - " You must provide a value expression following the '+' operator."

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm currently running this yaml file:

```
trigger:
- none
## notes 
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

## Job to calculate semantic version
jobs:
  - job: CalculateVersion
    displayName: Semantic versioning
    
    steps:
      # Checkout with persist credentials
      - checkout: self
        persistCredentials: true

      # Install GitVersion
      - task: gitversion/setup@0
        displayName: Install GitVersion
        inputs:
          versionSpec: '5.x'

      # Retrieve Pull Request Description
      - task: PullRequestDescription@0
        name: RetrievePullRequestDescription
        displayName: Retrieve Pull Request description
        inputs:
          action: 'view'
          outputVariable: 'PullRequest.DescriptionContent'
          isOutput: true
          stripIdentifiers: false

      # Add git commit message that will be picked up by GitVersion ("+semver: patch/minor/major")
      # Depending on the Pull Request description, where the developer has marked the type of change
      - task: PowerShell@2
        displayName: Add git commit message for SemVer
        inputs:
          targetType: inline
          script: |
            Write-Host "Configuring git author info.." -ForegroundColor Cyan
          
            git config user.email "alan.haro@datashieldprotect.com"
            git config user.name "alan.haro"
            Write-Host "Doing git checkout..." -ForegroundColor Cyan
            git checkout -b $("$(System.PullRequest.SourceBranch)".replace('refs/heads/creating-git-tags', ''))
            Write-Host "Checking Pull Request description..." -ForegroundColor Cyan
            $PRdesc = "$(RetrievePullRequestDescription.PullRequest.DescriptionContent)"
            if ($PRdesc -match '(\[x\] \bFix\b)') {
              Write-Host "Adding git (empty) commit message to mark this branch as a 'patch' SemVer increment." -ForegroundColor Cyan
              git commit -a -m "+semver: patch [skip azurepipelines]" --allow-empty
            } elseif ($PRdesc -match '(\[x\] \bFeature\b)') {
              Write-Host "Adding git (empty) commit message to mark this branch as a 'minor' SemVer increment." -ForegroundColor Cyan
              git commit -a -m "+semver: minor [skip azurepipelines]" --allow-empty
            } elseif ($PRdesc -match '(\[x\] \bBig\b)') {
              Write-Host "Adding git (empty) commit message to mark this branch as a 'major' SemVer increment." -ForegroundColor Cyan
              git commit -a -m "+semver: major [skip azurepipelines]" --allow-empty
            } else {
              Write-Host "##vso[task.LogIssue type=error;]Please select the type of change in the Pull Request description, and Re-queue the validation." -ForegroundColor Cyan
              $PRdesc
              exit 1
            }
            Write-Host "Doing git push.." -ForegroundColor Cyan
            git push --set-upstream origin $("$(System.PullRequest.SourceBranch)".replace('refs/heads/', ''))
            Write-Host "Done." -ForegroundColor Cyan
          
      # Determine the semantic version & test test
      - task: gitversion/execute@0
        displayName: Determine SemVer
```

To make sure this runs well, I will have to passed the following command in the comments from the new PR:

```
git commit -a -m "+'semver: minor [skip azurepipelines]'" --allow-empty
```

By doing this, I will have the following issue:

"  You must provide a value expression following the '+' operator."

Does anyone knows what else I can do to prevent this type of error messages?

Comment: I am not sure. Try wrapping the string with single quotes **'+semver: patch [skip azurepipelines]'**

Answer (score -2):

I solved my problem by adding the following template inside of my PR description:

Description
Thank you for your contribution to the Bla Bla repo.
Before submitting this PR, please make sure:

- [ ]  Fix
- [ ]  Feature
- [ ]  Big

Note: If you would like to have different terminology, you will have to change the regex part. As an example:

```
 if ($PRdesc -match '(\[x\] \**bFix**\b)')
```

At the same time, you will have to make a change inside of the checkboxes that you added inside of the Pull Request to make sure it will match.

Now, the script is working.  If you would like to see a guide to add semantic versioning to your project, you will have to look at the guide's creator link: https://www.moderndata.ai/2021/10/automatic-semantic-versioning-in-azure-devops-with-release-notes/. Look at the main issue that I created - [$(System.PullRequest.SourceBranch) no found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70074863/system-pullrequest-sourcebranch-no-found/70100125#70100125).

Comment: Your original quest is a git commit error. How does your answer solve the problem?

Comment: Add git commit message for SemVer Powershell scripts have some regex that will take in place the checkboxes to make sure I will be able to declare if my Pull Request will be a Fix, Feature or Big. 

By adding the form above in the PR-Comments solved the issue

Comment: That's my answer, I added the template for my comments inside of my PR, and choose the option that I need. Read the script, and you will see that regex is asking you for checkboxes, and if you add those inside of your PR comments, you will be able to play with this script.

The script itself has nothing wrong, and I didn't understand it at the beginning, but now I solved and I'm sharing the guide that I followed